# google script running steps

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

my program is like this :

//google script

```
 1. function F1() { ...... return (v1); }
```

// google html

```
1. <script>
 2. function F2() {
 3.   alert ( 1 );
 4.   function F2();
 5.   alert ( 2 );
 6.   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(F3).F1();
 7.   alert ( 4 );
 8. }
 9. 
 10. function F3(data) {
 11.   alert ( 3 );
 12.    ......;
 13. } </script>
```

my problem is, when the "function F2" is called, 
I thought the steps will be : 1-2-3-4;
but the alert popup is : 1-2-4-3

is it correct ?

Comment: If F3 is called asynchronously (which it appears it is), then this is entirely correct.  F3 is called when `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()` finishes which is sometime later, but the rest of your script continues to run in the meantime.  This is how asynchronous operations in Javascript work.

Comment: so if I want to get a value from the F1 and let it work with something, the data will be wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run says:

> google.script.run is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API available in HTML-service pages that can call server-side Apps Script functions.

This means that F3 is not executed immediately, but instead when the response from server arrives. Execution of F2 does not stop and wait for the response from server.